# Update object by reference in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a simple function which accepts list of objects as an argument and calls one of the objects methods to update the property on each object:

```
void updateList( std::map<std::string, MyCustomObject> *myList )
{
    for each( std::pair< std::string, MyCustomObject > p in *myList )
    {
        std::string currentObjectKey = p.first;
        MyCustomObject    *currentObject     = &p.second;
        currentObject->setName( "NewName" );
    }
}
```

And here is MyCustomObject class:

```
void MyCustomObject::setName(std::string newName)
{
    name = newName;
}

std::string MyCustomObject::getName()
{
    name = newName;
}
```

The problem is that if I do another loop to read the values updated, I get the original values from when I initialized the list, instead of my new "NewName" value. It seems like the 'p' variable in the for each loop is a copy instead of a reference, therefor it's not really updating.

How can I update the value and access the object by reference instead of a copy?

Comment: `for each( std::pair< std::string, MyCustomObject >& p in *myList )` ampersand or `for(auto& p : mylist)`

Comment: What is `each` and `in`?

Comment: @Angew that MS managed C++ I believe, OP you better use proper tag, this is not a valid C++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
for each(std::pair<std::string, MyCustomObject> p : *myList)
```

has no effect because it copies the elements of the `container`. Adjust your code to:

```
for(auto& pair : *myList)
{
    std::string currentObjectKey = p.first;
    MyCustomObject* currentObject = &p.second;
    currentObject->setName("NewName");
}
```

Final notes, `don't` pass strings by value(setName for example). If you intent to inspect the string then a plain `string const&` or a `string_view` is the best option(cause you don't copy anything). Pass by `reference` if you want to modify and by value if you can cheap copy (e.g. an int or a float)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and hit, worked like a charm! :)

Comment: "Don't pass strings by value" - that's not always true. In this specific case (where the string is assigned to a member variable), passing by value is actually the fastest way in some cases, specifically when the caller constructs a new string object every time. string_view is by far the fastest bar none when the caller passes a string literal, but slowest when a new string object is created.

Comment: @riv it's not all about speed(which passing by value means a deep copy) but about readability and code intention. If you want a `non modifiable` string then you simply don't pass it by value to make your intentions clear and your life easier(and at the same time you get the best performance -- you are happy, your team is happy). Similar thinking applies to all the cases.

Comment: @KostasRim Passing by value does not always mean a deep copy. Sometimes, a pass by value can be just a move where a pass by const reference forces a copy, depending on what you do with the parameter inside the function. Google the article "Want speed? Pass by value."

Comment: @Angew you are referring to `move semantics` and that's not always the case :). On cppcoreguidelines pass value is suggested for cheap to copy entities(ints, char etc). Moreover, when you pass by `const reference` unless you have some form of weird type deduction or a temporary object(that will be moved), nothing is copied.

Comment: @KostasRim I'm talking about [cases like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31757fb8cd3ce72a).

Comment: @Angew foo() returns a `temporary` and after C++17 its guaranteed to be temporarily materialized (that is, moved). Now for the last two, `unavoidable_copy` doesn't copy when the argument is passed but later on the assignment statement. Both cases do `exactly 1` copy. (You can verify that by wrapping the std::string into a wrapper and provide the appropriate constructors that print their respective operation). In the first function you copy and then possibly move, whereas the second you move and then you copy

Comment: @Angew Uh I see your point now, the one assigns the other moves. In these cases you probably care about the `value category` and you should be looking at `std::forward` anyway.

Comment: @KostasRim Yes, perfect forwarding is of course the best for this, but it comes with the downside of requiring a template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191908/discussion-between-kostasrim-and-angew).